# Add objective-c plugin to swift project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need help with using this customizeable checkbox:
https://github.com/Marxon13/M13Checkbox
I have already linked m13checkbox.h and .m classes and wrote import in bridge-header file, but i don't know how to create `checkbox` on my `tableview` and manipulate it.

I need to place `checkbox` in every cell by my own `UITableCell` class.

**UPD.**

I have done with adding `checkbox` in cell, but now i need to control it in addiction by my data in `UITableViewController`. I need to set `checkbox` to checked/unchecked state depending on my dataArray. I also need to set label for every `checkbox` from dataArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom `UITableViewCell` subclass, you should declare a property similar to the following

```
@IBOutlet weak var checkbox: M13Checkbox!
```

Then, in the corresponding prototype cell in your Storyboard:

1. Drag out a UIView from the Object Library.
2. Change the class of that view to "M13Checkbox" in the Identity Inspector.
3. Position the checkbox and add any necessary Auto Layout constraints.
4. In the corresponding table view's data source, make sure that you are dequeuing cells with the correct identifiers.

When that UITableView is on screen, you should see a checkbox in each cell, assuming your `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` method returns an integer greater than zero.